SSL Error : net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID while loading Express and NodeJS API
I've been facing this error and even after a lot of research on SO, I have not been able to solve it. Here what I did :

I first have followed the steps indicated here in order to create my self-signed certificate.
Then, I added it to my Node.js server code :

const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const cors = require('cors');
const csvParser = require('csv-parser');
const https = require('https');

const app = express();
const port = 30440;

app.get('/read-data', (req, res) => {
    const results = [];

    fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
        .pipe(csvParser())
        .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
        .on('end', () => {
            res.json(results);
        })
        .on('error', (error) => {
            console.error('Error reading CSV:', error);
            res.status(500).send('Error reading CSV');
        });
});

const private = fs.readFileSync('client-key.pem', 'utf8');
const cert = fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem', 'utf8');

const certificate = {key: private, cert: cert};

https.createServer(certificate, app).listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on https://grumpycoincat.xyz:${port}`);
})


And here is a part of the client code :

const response = fetch('https://IP_ADDRESS:30440/read-data')

I'm currently testing in production, because in development the browser doesn't care about the localhost.
Thanks in advance

If you have a self-signed certificate you need to import it into the browser as trusted, otherwise the browser will complain. Also, the identity inside the certificate (SAN) must match the URL you use to call the server, which is not clear here (but calling by IP address looks suspicious).

But when I'll be in production, the certificate will must be imported by the user right ? And how can I call my URL with a port ?

It is a bad idea to use self-signed certificates in production since these must be imported as trusted by every client - and must be imported again if the certificate gets renewed. And the port is irrelevant for the certificate, only the host part of the URL matters for validation.
